# return zero instead of nothing when no rows in the corresponding index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, indexing

I have the following code

```
count_by_month=df.groupby('month')['activity'].nunique()
month=list(range(0,12,1))
count_by_month.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(month),:]
```

The above code return the following data:

| month | activity |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 12 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 9 | 15 |
| 12 | 10 |

I want the following it  to return 0 instead of nothing when no item in the corresponding month value. i.e. if no data corresponding to month two then I want to include the index of 2 with zero in all columns. so the desired outbut should looks like the following:

| month | activity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 15 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 |
| 12 | 10 |

I want to do this because I want to see the whole months set as an index on the X axses when plotting the data.
If this is not possible then  can we plot  whole months index not only limited to where the data exist??

```
count_by_month.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(month),:].plot(kind='bar')
```

Thanks for suggestion..

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: Hey @mozway, I edited the question so you can see the outcomes and the desired outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution:
modifying the code to looks like the following work :

```
count_by_month.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(month),:].reindex(month, fill_value=0)
```